# To show that something is a four-vector

Tags: vector-spaces, metric-spaces, tensors

I hope this question is not too inane... it would be really helpful for me to have this cleared up.  I want to know what I need to show to demonstrate that something is a four-vector. I have checked the definition of the [four-vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-vector) but I am still not sure.

Take as an example the Maxwell equation $$\partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu}=-\mu_0 J^\nu$$
I know that Minkowski spacetime is flat so since $F^{\mu\nu}$ is a tensor, $\partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu}$ is a vector (Am I right so far?). Does it  then follow that $J^\nu$ is a 4-vector? Or do I have to check something to do with the Lorentz transformation?

My apologies again if this is  rather confusing. I am new to these things and am truly rather confused. Thanks for reading!

Comment: I think computing the divergence (that is taking $\partial_\nu$ should be sufficient to show that it's a four-vector since the result is $0$ which is a scalar.

Comment: @Raskolnikov: Thanks for replying, and so promptly too! :) May I ask why the div of $J$ being a scalar shows that it's a 4-vec?

Comment: Is showing that something is a 4-vector basically the same as showing that it is a "tensor" with one index?

Comment: @Benny yes. exactly.

Comment: There is a theorem that says that when you contract a tensor, the result is also a tensor and if a tensor is the contraction of something, then that something is a tensor. That's what I use. Don't remember the exact name of the theorem.

Comment: @Raskolnikov: So the theorem extends to operators on tensors -- like $\partial_\mu$?

Comment: Yeah, it works as well.